# Typescript fail checking for properties in the union of a function type and a object type

Tags: typescript

Typescript fail checking for properties in the union of a function type and a object type intercepted with another union of objects and function.

This is a minimal repo for reproduce the issue. What be the correct way of archive this?

```
type Component = () => {};
type OneType =
  | Component
  | { component: Component }
  | { getComponent: () => Component }

type AnotherType =
  | Component
  | ({ // static properties of Component
    option?: string;
    anotherOption?: string;
  } & OneType);

type AnyObject = {
  [name: string]: AnotherType
}

function aFunction(comps: AnyObject, name: string) {
  const comp = comps[name];

  // [ts] fail here: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'AnotherType'
  if (comp.component) {
    return comp.component;
  }

  // [ts] fail here: Property 'getComponent' does not exist on type 'AnotherType'
  if (typeof comp.getComponent === 'function') {
    return comp.getComponent();
  }

  return comp;
}
```

This is the Playgroud: [Playground repo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Atype%20Component%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20OneType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20Component%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%20component%3A%20Component%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%20getComponent%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Component%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AnotherType%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20Component%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20(%7B%20%2F%2F%20static%20properties%20of%20Component%0D%0A%20%20%20%20option%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20anotherOption%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%26%20OneType)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AnyObject%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20AnotherType%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20aFunction(comps%3A%20AnyObject%2C%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20comp%20%3D%20comps%5Bname%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%5Bts%5D%20fail%20here%3A%20Property%20'component'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'AnotherType'%0D%0A%20%20if%20(comp.component)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20comp.component%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%5Bts%5D%20fail%20here%3A%20Property%20'getComponent'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'AnotherType'%0D%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20comp.getComponent%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20comp.getComponent()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20comp%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 6):

Typescript will only let you access common properties in a union. One solution is to use an `in` type-guard to convince the compiler of which member of the union you are talking about.

```
type Component = () => {};
type OneType =
  | Component
  | { component: Component }
  | { getComponent: () => Component }

type AnotherType =
  | Component
  | ({ // static properties of Component
    option?: string;
    anotherOption?: string;
  } & OneType);

type AnyObject = {
  [name: string]: AnotherType
}

function aFunction(comps: AnyObject, name: string) {
  const comp = comps[name];

  // ok
  if ('component' in comp) {
    return comp.component;
  }

  // ok
  if ('getComponent' in comp && typeof comp.getComponent === 'function') {
    return comp.getComponent();
  }

  return comp;
}
```

In 3.2 with null checks enabled, you can also declare the missing properties on all members of the union, but declare them as optional and if type `undefined`. This will let you acces the properties on the union, and since their types don't overlap Typescript will treat this as a discriminated union and do the expected type narrowing when you check the properties.

```
type Component = () => {};
type OneType =
  | (Component & { component?: undefined, getComponent?: undefined})
  | { component: Component }
  | { getComponent: () => Component, component?: undefined}

type AnotherType =
  | (Component & { component?: undefined, getComponent?: undefined})
  | ({ // static properties of Component
    option?: string;
    anotherOption?: string;
  } & OneType);

type AnyObject = {
  [name: string]: AnotherType
}

function aFunction(comps: AnyObject, name: string) {
  const comp = comps[name];
{
  if (comp.component) {
    return comp.component;
  }

  if (typeof comp.getComponent === 'function') {
    return comp.getComponent();
  }

  return comp;
}
```

Comment: I like the type guard solution. The typescript 3.2 approach looks more weired in this case

Comment: @scrapy_user one changes the code, the other just definitions .. both can work. I would use the first one too, but I mentioned all the valid options I can think of and let you choose :)

Comment: The "if ('getComponent' in comp && typeof comp.getComponent === 'function')" part don't like than much. Now two checks are need on place of one. This is the sad part :-(. The one typeof "function" was beautiful, now is redundant.

Comment: @scrapy_user can't have it all in this case unfortunately... you can either take the ugly typings (and the restrictions that apply) or add extra checks. You can also just use type assertions, but ideally you would avoid those :)

Comment: Not problem, if I needed more performance in code I will put 'any' to all function values. Thx for the great support Titian.